# sign up problem, JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want register. post json request.  Consol log json data, i have under sign up text "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data".

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SingUp() {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const res = await fetch("/api/auth/signup", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData),
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      console.log(data);
      if (data.success === false) {
        setLoadnig(false);
        setError(data.message);
        return;
      }
      setLoading(false);
      setError(null);
      navigate("/sign-in");
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="p-3 max-w-lg mx-auto">
      <h1
        className="text-3xl text-center font-semibold
      my-7"
      >
        Sign Up
      </h1>
      <form className="flex flex-col gap-4">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
          className="bord p-3 rounded-lg"
          id="username"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="email"
          placeholder="email"
          className="bord p-3 rounded-lg"
          id="email"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          placeholder="password"
          className="bord p-3 rounded-lg"
          id="password"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button
          disabled={loading}
          className="bg-slate-700 text-white p-3 rounded-lg uppercase hover:opacity-95 disabled:opacity-80"
        >
          {loading ? "Loading..." : "Sign Up"}
        </button>
      </form>
      <div className="flex gap-2 mt-5">
        <p>Have an account?</p>
        <Link to={"/sign-in"}>
          <span className="text-blue-700">Sign in</span>
        </Link>
      </div>
      {error && <p className="text-red-500 mt-5">{error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

i want register. post json request.  Consol log json data, i have under sign up text "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data".

i try to send inf to server, and i get "POST
http://localhost:5173/api/auth/signup
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 4065ms]

```
"auth.controller.js:"

import User from "../models/user.model.js";
import bcryptjs from "bcryptjs";
import { errorHandler } from "../utils/error.js";

export const signup = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;
  const hashedPassword = bcryptjs.hashSync(password, 10);
  const newUser = new User({ username, email, password: hashedPassword });
  try {
    await newUser.save();
    res.status(201).json("User created successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

error server site:
throw Error("Illegal arguments: "+(typeof s)+', '+(typeof salt));
^

Error: Illegal arguments: undefined, string

Comment: Look at your logs ..  `api/auth/signup` itself (or the server) will have an error logged with your specific problem.

Comment: Hard to say. Look at the logs or provide api/auth/signup code.

Comment: i just edit post and add "auth.controller.js"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps change the response to:

```
res.status(201).json({ "message": "User created successfully" });
```

Here, you have a valid JSON, and you should be able to read the data properly from the "message" field.